# Model and countermodel to $\exists x.\forall y. x<y$ (with $<$ an arbitrary relation)

Tags: logic, relations, predicate-logic

Can someone please help me with this question. I have been struggling with it for ages and can't quite seem to work it out:

> Let $<$ be a binary relation symbol that we will write infix. Let $\phi = \exists x.\forall y.x<y$. Define structures $A,B$ such that $A \models \phi$ and $B \not\models \phi$.

I would be really grateful of any help.

Comment: You don't get to delete the evidence boyo ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The symbol chosen to represent the relation is a **big** hint. Suppose that $<$ really is, as the symbol suggests, some kind of order relation. Then $\varphi$ just says that there is a smallest element with respect to $<$. Can you think of sets $A$ and $B$ and relations on $A$ and $B$ for which we normally use the symbol $<$ or $\le$ such that $A$ does have a smallest element with respect to the, and $B$ does not?

Comment: One little bit of sloppiness with respect to the symbol chosen for the question as presented: For the model to hold it must be the case that $x\lt x$, so it can't be anti-reflexive the way 'less than' is.

Comment: @Steven: True, and the original version of my answer was also a bit careless. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for the hint, I'm not quite sure on how I would find and lay out the answer though.

Comment: @user42701: What are some simple sets with order relations that you know?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I'm working with a friend and we're both unsure on what an order relation is. Could be the fact that we've been working on this for several hours now, and its getting quite late here!

Comment: @user42701: Does $\langle\Bbb N,\le\rangle\vDash\varphi$, where $\le$ is just ordinary less-than-or-equal-to, and $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers, $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I've got to be honest, we have absolutely no idea about this whole question. We are really struggling with the whole of relations in logic.

Comment: @user42701: Hm. Do you understand what the following expression means? $$\exists x\in\Bbb N\,\forall y\in\Bbb N(x\le y)$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, we do understand that.

Comment: @user42701: Okay; is it a true statement?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes we think it's true, for example when x = 0.

Comment: @user42701: That’s right. And that means that the structure $\langle\Bbb N,\le\rangle$ does satisfy the sentence $\varphi$: $\varphi$ is true in $\Bbb N$ when you interpret the relation symbol $<$ as ordinary $\le$. Now what happens if you change $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$, the set of **all** integers?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: The only way for this to be true would be if x was negative infinity?

Comment: @user42701: And there is no such integer. No matter what integer you choose for $x$, $x-1$ is also an integer, and it’s not true that $x\le x-1$. Thus, $\langle\Bbb Z,\le\rangle\not\vDash\varphi$: the sentence $\varphi$ is not true in the structure $\langle\Bbb Z,\le\rangle$ when the abstract relation symbol $<$ is interpreted as ordinary $\le$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: So presumably that would be what B equals? Since it ⊭φ?

Comment: @user42701: Yes, that would be one possible choice for $B$. There are lots of choice for both, some of them almost as familiar as these, but I thought that these two would probably be the simplest.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: We now both understand everything that you have said, and can now finally get some sleep! Thank you very much for you help in leading us through it while we were stuck!

Comment: @user42701: You’re very welcome. And for goodness’ sake get some sleep! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- You have no constraints on the relation whatsoever.
- You have no constraints on the universe either.
- In a universe of size $1$ the meaning of quantifiers is rather straightforward.
- There are only a few relations $ \subseteq \{\spadesuit\} \times \{\spadesuit\}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$